# Azure DevOps in Git what do blue and gray dot mean in graph

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos

Azure DevOps in Git what do blue and gray dot mean in graph as code branches and merges. Can any one share link which explains all this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Git graph experience:

- The blue dots represent any commit in the repo or a file
- The grey dots represent a merge commit.
- A line connects a commit to its ancestor commit. In case a commit does not show its parent within the next 50 commits, you will see an arrow that once clicked will connect the commit to its parent commit.

See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/05/10/announcing-git-graph-and-advanced-filters-to-visualize-commit-history/) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/06/25/supercharging-the-git-commit-graph/) more info.

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is completely right. More specifically I think the grey dots represents commits with two parents (which is only possible to get by merging) - but a fast-forward merge is a  merge that only results in new commits with a single parents (and in the graph we get blue dots).